# How do I use range to make a list with other values?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, loops, append

I currently want the following output:

```
[161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 13362, 13363, 13364, 13365, 13366, 13367, 13368, 13369, 13370, 13383, 13384, 11100, 667, 6503, 6506, 666]
```

(more condensed version:)

```
[161...172, 13362...13370, 13383, 13384, 11100, 667, 6503, 6506, 666]
```

So I figured out to do it like this:

```
emoteIds = range(161, 173)
for i in range(13362, 13371):
    emoteIds.append(i)
for i in [13383, 13384, 11100, 667, 6503, 6506, 666]:
    emoteIds.append(i)
```

However, I feel that this can be condensed. Is there any way for me to incorporate `range()` in the list without it making another list in the list? I tried using the `list()` function, but to no avail.

Comment: Given that you can use `append()` *at all* I can only conclude you are using Python 2 here, so I tagged your question as such.

Comment: I am using Python 3, but am not aware of much.

Comment: Your code, as posted, can't work in Python 3, because range objects there are immutable sequences. They can't be appended to.

Comment: My apologies, it's 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use loops; just concatenate the list objects:

```
emoteIds = range(161, 173) + range(13362, 13371) + [
    13383, 13384, 11100, 667, 6503, 6506, 666]
```

(In Python 3, you'd have to use `list()` calls to convert the `range()` objects to actual lists).

You may want to look at [`list.extend()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) as well; you could have used:

```
emoteIds = range(161, 173)
emoteIds.extend(range(13362, 13371))
emoteIds.extend([13383, 13384, 11100, 667, 6503, 6506, 666])
```

or a `+=` augmented assignment, which comes down to the same thing as `list.extend()` here:

```
emoteIds = range(161, 173)
emoteIds += range(13362, 13371))
emoteIds += [13383, 13384, 11100, 667, 6503, 6506, 666]
```

Comment: Any suggestion with `itertools.chain`? (Beautiful hat Martijn)

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE: that'd make sense if you didn't already have 3 list objects, and if you only needed to iterate. In Python 3, or using `xrange()`, *and* all you do is iterate, then just use `itertools.chain(range(...), range(...),  [...])` yes.

Answer (score 0):

With [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) that does the range creating under the hood for you -

```
 np.r_[161:173, 13362:13371, 13383, 13384, 11100, 667, 6503, 6506, 666]
```

Sample run -

```
In [461]: np.r_[161:173, 13362:13371, 13383, 13384, 11100, 667, 6503, 6506, 666]
Out[461]: 
array([  161,   162,   163,   164,   165,   166,   167,   168,   169,
         170,   171,   172, 13362, 13363, 13364, 13365, 13366, 13367,
       13368, 13369, 13370, 13383, 13384, 11100,   667,  6503,  6506,   666])
```

If you need a list as output, use [`.tolist()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) method at the end -

```
np.r_[161:173, 13362:13371, 13383, 13384, 11100, 667, 6503, 6506, 666].tolist()
```